# Program To Find the Last Element in the List?

Tags: haskell

```
mylast :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a
mylast x:[] = "Last element is " ++ x
mylast x:xs = mylast xs
```

I wanted to find the last element of a List L given as input to mylast function.
As the List may contain integers or characters or strings I used Eq typeclass for indicating that type of elements of the list should belong to Eq.But I am getting the Following Error:
       *LastEle.hs:2:1: Parse error in pattern: mylast*

Comment: Missing parens (`mylast (x:[]) = ...`). Also you can't return a `String` from a function that's supposed to return `a`, neither can you append `x` to it.

Comment: You don't need `Eq` qualification either since `last` doesn't depend on the identity of the elements, just the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are wrong.

You need parentheses around your pattern matching for `(x:[])` and `(x:xs)`.

You are also missing a case for the empty list, so it will crash. A safer way of handling this is to use `Maybe`, returning `Nothing` on an empty list. You *could* let your program crash on an empty list, but that's generally considered bad form. The `Maybe` type allows you to explicitly state, in the most simple manner, that your function may return a non-successful result. In other languages, you might return a `null` on bad input.

You don't need the `Eq` typeclass because you aren't comparing anything. Furthermore, you are returning a String when your declaration says you should be returning a value of type `a`. I recommend this implementation:

```haskell
mylast :: [a] -> Maybe a
mylast [] = Nothing
mylast (x:[]) = Just x
mylast (_:xs) = mylast xs
```

Now you can use the result of `mylast` to display the original text you showed in your example, plus you can show a friendly message (rather than crashing) if an empty list was provided:

```haskell
displayLast :: Show a => [a] -> String
displayLast list =
  case mylast list of
    Nothing -> "The list was empty!"
    Just lastItem -> "Last element is " ++ (show lastItem)
```

Comment: You might want to explain why it is that the `Maybe a` result is so much more useful than the attempted `String` result. That's obvious to us, but it might smell of needless abstraction to a newcomer.

Comment: @Chad Gilbert I tried to run the script by Removing Just And it was throwing an error.What does  Just Actually do ?

Comment: @v.sharathchandra - I updated my answer with an example of how to use the return value of the `Maybe a` returned by `mylast` by returning a string that describes the contents. Think of `Just` as a wrapper around a successful value.

Answer (score -2):

```
Prelude> :info last
last :: [a] -> a        -- Defined in `GHC.List'

Prelude> last [1..10]
10

Prelude> last []
*** Exception: Prelude.last: empty list
```